# Piping Objects From Format-Table to Export-CSV Has Unexpected Results

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, activesync

I'm running this command to get a list of all Activesync users and export them to C:\activesync.csv

```
Get-ActiveSyncDevice | Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics | sort-object status, devicetype , lastsyncattempttime | ft  FirstSyncTime   ,LastPolicyUpdateTime   ,LastSyncAttemptTime    ,LastSuccessSync , DeviceType , DeviceID, DeviceAccessState, Identity -a | Export-Csv c:\activesync.csv
```

The problem is that the CSV data doesn't match the console display if I omit the trailing `| c:\activesync.csv`  ... where the data and columns displayed don't match.

Is this a bug in powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to remember is that everything in PowerShell is an object.  When you use Format-Table, the output is a formatting object and that's what is getting passed in to export CSV.  If you pipe the results of the Format-Table command to Get-Member, you'll see what I mean.

```
Get-ActiveSyncDevice | 
  Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics | 
  sort-object status, devicetype , lastsyncattempttime | 
  Format-Table FirstSyncTime   ,LastPolicyUpdateTime   ,LastSyncAttemptTime    ,LastSuccessSync , DeviceType , DeviceID, DeviceAccessState, Identity -a | 
  Get-Member
```

The output of that will be a series of descriptions of various formatting objects.

Format-Table is great for creating output in your console session or sending formatted output to a text file (using out-file), but if we change your Format-Table to Select-Object, your CSV file will be more of what you expect.

```
Get-ActiveSyncDevice | 
  Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics | 
  sort-object status, devicetype , lastsyncattempttime | 
  select  FirstSyncTime   ,LastPolicyUpdateTime   ,LastSyncAttemptTime    ,LastSuccessSync , DeviceType , DeviceID, DeviceAccessState, Identity | 
  Export-Csv c:\activesync.csv
```

(Side note.. for long pipelines the pipe character can be used as a line continuation.)